# Implementing a curried map function in Swift

Tags: swift

Attempting to write a curried **map** function in Swift:

```swift
import Foundation

func add(_ a: Int) -> ((Int) -> Int) {
    return {a + $0}
}

// map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
func map<A,B>(_ f: (A) -> B) -> (([A]) -> [B]) {
    return {$0.map(f)}
}
```

However, I get two error messages:

`parameter 'f' is implicitly non-escaping`

and,

`escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'f'`

Can someone explain what wrong with my function and how can I solve it ?

What's the meaning of "non-escaping" in this context ?

Comment: You can fix the error by using `f: @escaping (A) -> B)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a warning: many techniques that are commonly used in FP languages, including currying, are completely possible in Swift, but extremely inconvenient. They often become so wordy that they lose their value. The early versions of Swift had currying built-in, and it was intentionally removed because it causes a lot of headaches in Swift. This does not mean that higher-order functions are a problem, or functions that return functions. And even currying itself can be useful sometimes. But as a rule it isn't in Swift.

The point of `@escaping` is that the closure may "escape" the current context, and therefore there are different memory management concerns. This changes whether `self.` is required in the closures. To resolve it, you need to tell the system that you are aware of this, and warn the caller, by adding `@escaping`.

```
func map<A,B>(_ f: @escaping (A) -> B) -> (([A]) -> [B]) {
```

In this case, the closure `f` outlives the call to `map()`, and so anything that `f` captures may have a lifespan longer than the caller might otherwise expect, and potentially could lead to strong reference cycles. Most FP-friendly languages have garbage collection that can handle cycles. Swift uses ARC for automatic memory management. It's more deterministic and has more predictable performance, but cannot handle cycles, so certain things that are natural in FP-friendly languages don't translate easily.

See [Escaping Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) in the Swift Programming Language for full details.

As a rule, Swift composes with types (especially structs) by using protocols and extensions, rather than by composing functions, objects, or algebraic types as you might in other languages.